# Adjust the height of bsCollapsePanel in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, height, panel, shinybs

I'm using the `shinyBS` package in a shiny app and I'm struggle with adjusting the height of the panel ! I have tried to put the `height=100%` in `bsCollapse` and `bsCollapsePanel` but it did not work !

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(collapsibleTree)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  useShinyjs(),

  navbarPage(HTML("MyApp"),
             tabPanel("Home", 

                  bsCollapse(id = "output_data_all", multiple = TRUE,open = "Data",
                                        
                        bsCollapsePanel("Data", style = "info",
                                       
                            selectInput(inputId = 'Ind1',
                                        label = 'Select Container',
                                        choices = c(),
                                        selected = NULL),
                                        br(),br(),
                                        withSpinner(collapsibleTreeOutput("t1"),type=5),
                                        br(),br()
                                              
                                        ))
                      
             )
  )
)
Server <- function(input, output,session){
  
  output$t1 <- renderCollapsibleTree({
    
  })
}
```

Comment: How do you want to change the height? Please specify.

Comment: @Iz100, I think it is clear : `height=100%` ? I would like the `bsCollapsePanel` fill the entire page, in the current version in my code is just half of the page which I could not change it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose the contents of the panel in a `div` with `style = "height: 70vh"` (adjust 70 as you want - this means 70% of the viewport height):

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  useShinyjs(),

  navbarPage(
    HTML("MyApp"),
      tabPanel("Home", 

        bsCollapse(id = "output_data_all", multiple = TRUE,open = "Data",
       
                    bsCollapsePanel("Data", style = "info",

                        div(
                        style = "height: 70vh",                                       
                                selectInput(inputId = 'Ind1',
                                        label = 'Select Container',
                                        choices = c(),
                                        selected = NULL),
                                br(),br(),
                                    withSpinner(collapsibleTreeOutput("t1"),type=5),
                                br(),br()
                                              
                            )
                )
                      
             )
    )
  )
)
```